# Only grow flexbox to window size, not for content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have 2 divs fill the screen, one being at the bottom of the page and one being the "main" content area.

I've created a jsfiddle to demonstrate what I need: https://jsfiddle.net/zmnogytL/1/
The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="messages">
        <span id="jstext"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-area"></div>
</div>
```

The main div (the gray one) shouldn't expand when the content exceeds its height, but instead have a scrollbar within it.
The lower div(blue) should always stay in the same spot.

After countless hours I'm still not getting it to work the way I want to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does the blue div have a fix height?

Comment: Yes, the blue div is always 100px in height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
.messages{
  overflow:scroll;
  max-height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: Seems to work with the example fiddle, however it doesn't seem to work in my actual application. I'll still accept this answer, as it does answer the question I initially asked.

Comment: Is this fiddle different from your problem?

Comment: Yes, my main problem is within an angular app that is within a few more divs, which all rely on flexboxes.

Comment: If you are using flexbox. Your child element can not be set a fixed height. Just use max-height and min-height instead.